# creating an hexxagon game need help with the bord

Tags: algorithm

I'm going to create hexagon game and I need to create an hexagon board...
I need to draw a board with 61 hexagons so I need a short formula an hexagon I will be happy if someone will give me a formula to create that quickly :)
thanks boaz

I'm programming in java.....

The board need to be with 61 hexagons...

Comment: You're going to have to give a lot more information about your problem before anyone can help you.

Comment: The question is badly formulated but does it deserve to be closed? OP is asking for an algorithm to draw a grid of hexagons and doesn't want to be bothered with the math behind it. I guess answers might be of interest for other programmers that want to do that as well...

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar last year, here is a simplified version of my code that might help you:

```
public class MapPanel {

    int r = 30; // radius of hexagone
    int h = (int) Math.sqrt(r*r*3/4);
    int[] xPoints = {r/2,3*r/2,2*r,3*r/2,r/2,0};
    int[] yPoints = {0,0,h,2*h,2*h,h};
    int[] xp = new int[6];
    int[] yp = new int[6];

    public void paint(Graphics g){

        int xoffset = 0;
        int yoffset = 0;

        // display map
        for (int j = 0; j < /* put width here */; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < /* put height here */; i++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < 6; k++) {
                    xp[k] = xPoints[k]+xoffset;
                    yp[k] = yPoints[k]+yoffset;
                }
                g.setColor(Color.black);
                g.drawPolygon(xp, yp, 6);
                yoffset += 2*h;
            }
            yoffset = h-yoffset % (2*h);
            xoffset += 3*r/2;
        }   
    }
}
```

If you want explanations of the formulas just google "hexagon"...